# PosgreSQL select distinct with sum recursively

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 2 columns `name` and `balance`. It contains multiple entries for transactions representing balances. for example, Clifford can appear thrice with two entries being positive and 1 entry being negative. I need a query that will return distinct users with three columns `name`, `negative_total` and `positive_total` for all users in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
selet name,
      sum(balance) filter (where balance < 0) as negative_total,
      sum(balance) filter (where balance > 0) as positive_total
from t
group by name;
```